# Convergence of Finite Difference Scheme for Helmholtz equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Consider the 2-dimensional Helmholtz equation

$$-\Delta u-k^2 u= f.$$

I'm trying to proof convergence of the standard finite difference scheme (using the 5-point-stencil for the Laplacian).
I have seen some proofs for the similar looking equation

$$-\Delta u+ cu= f$$

with $c\geq 0$. But since those proofs usually use some version of a maximum principle (which doesn't hold true for the Helmholtz equation), I'm stuck.
Does anyone have a reference for a proof where $c\geq 0$ isn't required?

Comment: it is not trivial. Even for 1D (in 1D, FEM of deg 1 and FDM are essentially the same), see Ihlenburg, Frank, and Ivo Babuška. "Finite element solution of the Helmholtz equation with high wave number Part I: The h-version of the FEM." Computers & Mathematics with Applications 30.9 (1995): 9-37. For 2D, there are plenty of works with 9 or more points stencils with PML or Robin bd, you can borrow their techniques to prove yours.

Comment: For FEM, the convergence is found in Melenk, Jens Markus, and Stefan Sauter. "Wavenumber explicit convergence analysis for Galerkin discretizations of the Helmholtz equation." SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis 49.3 (2011): 1210-1243. They probably have more recent works on this.